# How do I get the index of an object in this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
myArr:[obj{}. obj{}, obj{}, obj{}]
```

How can I return the index of each object in the array?
This snippet is inside a bigger for loop which will iterate the same amount of times as there are objects in my array.

```
var ret = 'Index: '

if(myArr.length > 0){
    var idx = myArr.obj.index??

    var ret += idx;
}

console.log(ret); //Which will hopefully be Index: 0 etc...
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: The list of indexes for the elementa of any array like the one you describe will always be `[0, 1, 2, 3, ... ]` - your question is hard to understand for that reason.

Comment: If you know the length then you know the number of objects which are in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment, but the array indexes will be a list of numbers from 0 to myArr.length - 1. To get the list you could do the following:

```
var arr = ["Hi", "How" "Are", "You"];
var indexes = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    indexes.push(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript `Array` provides an `indexOf` method that returns the index of the passed-in value:

```
var o1 = {foo: 'bar'}
var o2 = {foo: 'bar'}

var a = [o1, o2]

console.log(a.indexOf(o1)) // 0
console.log(a.indexOf(o2)) // 1
```